# React UseEffect wait until props have been processed to run

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that sets a user avatar. It needs to either show a logged in user image or a worker.

a worker is an optional prop passed, and logged in user profile image comes from redux state.

Basic version below. The issue is that the redux state image (logged in user) is there first, before it knows whether the prop worker is there or not.

The issue is that it is populating the logged in user image initially (as that is already available in redux state) and then changing to worker image. How can i delay the check and therefore setState until i know for sure props have been processed or not?

```
type IProps = {
  worker?: IUser;
};

const AvatarManager = ({ worker }: IProps) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>("");

  const profileImage = useSelector(getProfileImage);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (worker) {
      setImage(worker.profile_image);
      return;
    }
    if (profileImage) {
      setImage(profileImage);
    }
  }, [worker]);
}
```

Comment: Edited, so hopefully clearer. But essentially, the intial render doesnt have any props so it default loads logged in user image, then worker prop becomes available (its pass down tree from parent after api request), then it changes to worker profile image. I could setTimeout maybe, but maybe there is a better way to handle?

Answer (score 0):

I have passed an extra boolean prop to check whether i need to set worker image or logged in user image.

```
type IProps = {
  isWorkerImage?: boolean;
  worker?: IUser;
};

const AvatarManager = ({ isWorkerImage, worker }: IProps) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>("");

  const profileImage = useSelector(getProfileImage);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (worker) {
      setImage(worker.profile_image);
      return;
    }
    if (!isWorkerImage && profileImage) {
      setImage(profileImage);
    }
  }, [worker]);
}
```